Prove that the subgroup of $S_{4}$, $\langle (1 2), (1 3)(2 4) \rangle \cong D_{8}$
Is this supposed to be easy? $(1 \space 3)(2 \space 4)$ is rotation, and $(1 \space 2)$ is supposed to be reflection, but the latter are 2 adjacent vertices, how can you reflect them and leave the other pair intact? $(1 \space 2)$ is not even listed as element of $H$ subgroup here https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/D8_in_S4

Hint
The product $(13)(24)(12)=(1423).$
Meanwhile a presentation for $D_8$ is:  $$\langle a,b\mid a^4,b^2,(ba)^2\rangle. $$
You can use the relation $ab=ba^{-1}$ to prove that the order is at most $8.$
Then you can appeal to von Dyck's theorem.
Remark:  $D_8=\Bbb Z_4\rtimes \Bbb Z_2$ is the holomorph of $\Bbb Z_{\color{purple }{4}}.$  As such it does indeed embedd in $S_{\color{purple}{4}}.$
It's a Sylow-$2$ subgroup.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

$D_8$ is the symmetry group of a square.
Suppose, instead of numbering the vertices of the square in a sequential clockwise numbering we numbered them like this.

Now the action $(12)$ is a reflection across one of the diagonals, and $(13)(24)$ is a reflection across the vertical.  And show that this pair of reflections can generate the group.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
